# Select2 infinite scroll with groups

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, ui-select2, angularjs-select2

So this is an interesting situation that I haven't found any solutions on and am wondering if it's possible. I want to have a select2 box with infinite scrolling (paging) but I want to be able to group the results. One thing I know is that I will not need to insert data into groups that I haven't finished yet. Here's a use case:

A select2 box that will display users sorted by age groups. I have an age group 12-18 and I only want to pull back 10 users at a time. How can I add those users to the 12-18 age group?

Answer (score 0):

you didn't add an example code to your question so I provide a general solution.

First of all you have to create a `json` answer with children elements and you have to order it by the groups. It means Group1 can't come again after Group2 in the answer.

1st page:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "text": "Group1",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 1123,
          "text": "opt 1/1"
        },
        {
          "id": 1234,
          "text": "opt 1/2"
        },
        {
          "id": 1345,
          "text": "opt 1/3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "total": 963
}
```

2nd page

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "text": "Group1",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 1456,
          "text": "opt 1/4"
        },
        {
          "id": 1567,
          "text": "opt 1/5"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "Group2",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 2123,
          "text": "opt 2/1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "total": 963
}
```

3rd page

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "text": "Group2",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 2234,
          "text": "opt 2/2"
        },
        {
          "id": 2345,
          "text": "opt 2/3"
        },
        {
          "id": 2456,
          "text": "opt 2/4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "total": 963
}
```

Second, you need to remove the duplicated optgroups from the dropdown.

The appearance of search results in the dropdown (options and the optgroups) can be customized by using the templateResult option. I removed the duplicated optgroups and labels by this option.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mySelect2').select2({
        templateResult: formatOptions,
        ajax: {
            url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories',
            data: function (params) {
                // Query parameters will be ?search=[term]&page=[page]
                return {
                    search: params.term,
                    page: params.page || 1
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                params.page = params.page || 1;

                return {
                    results:    data.items,
                    pagination: {
                        more: (params.page * self.options.limit) < data.total
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    });

    function formatOptions(item, container, $el) {
        // optgroups section
        if (item.children && item.children.length > 0) {
            // don't format the repeated optgroups!
            if ($(".select2-results__group").text() === item.text) {
                return;
            }

            if ($('[aria-label="' + item.text + '"]').length > 0) {
                return;
            }

            // the first occasion of the given optgroup
            return $el;
        }

        // options section
        // here you can implement your own logic if you want to customise the output of the options
        $el.addClass('something-special-result result');

        return $el;
    }

});
```